# OrthographicCamera, Zoom Extent

Tags: c#, position, width, zooming, orthographic

I'm working with an OrthographicCamera and I need to make a zoom extent so I can see the whole scene even if the scene is rotated.

Basically, I'm actually doing this :

- Compute the Rect3D that includes all points of my scene :

  ```
  Rect3D boundTotal = new Rect3D(vertex[0], Size3D.Empty);
  for (i = 1; i < nbVertex; i++)
      boundTotal = Rect3D.Union(boundTotal, vertex[i]);
  ```
- Now, I'am computing the radius/diameter and the center of the sphere that include the 3D rectangle (that include all points of my scene) :

  ```
  Vector3D diagonal = new Vector3D(boundTotal.SizeX, boundTotal.SizeY, boundTotal.SizeZ);
  Point3D center = boundTotal.Location + (diagonal * 0.5);
  double diam = diagonal.Length;
  double radius = diam * 0.5;
  ```
- Finally, I move the camera position to the surface of the sphere along the look direction :

  ```
  Vector3D d = camera.LookDirection;  
  d.Normalize();  
  camera.Position = center - (radius * d);  
  camera.Width = diam;
  ```

The zoom is not done correctly... I don't see all the scene. Some parts of the scene are beyond the camera. Or perhaps the width is incorrect and constraint the view...

Can you help me ? (with a good tutorial or by pointing me where I made the mistake in my code)

Comment: Thank you :) I will remember next time :)